# Json parser issue with escaped double quote in Redshift

Tags: json, postgresql, amazon-web-services

As per [Redshift forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=158796&tstart=0) this is known issue.

I just used

```
json_extract_path_text(regexp_replace(event_properties,'\\\\\\\\.',''),'someValue')
```

but it is loading as

```
json_extract_path_text(regexp_replace(event_properties,'\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\.',''),'someValue')
```

I would like to set `standard_conforming_strings=true` in Redshift postgresql. Is this possible to set in Redshift? If yes, Can you guide me?

Comment: Does Redshift even have json functions?

Comment: I'm so confused. This "latest" docs says no http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html -- but OP's issue is (or will be) actually fixed https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2589

Comment: Enlightened: it has (some) json function support http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html , but not the json data type -- You could try `E'\\\\\\\\.'` or `$str$\\\\.$str$`, but i have to say: its a dirty hack.